# Post request with Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I use the following Node.js module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom

The problem is I don't know how to make a post request in order to login (or at least I need to fill the login form and click the button).

How can I do it? If not possible, is there any Node.js module that can be used to make post request or click a button on the page

Comment: You'd need to start programming. Break it down to small tasks and google each of them if you can't solve them on your own. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I have searched in google for some days . Please do not comment if you know nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any node package.

```
"use strict";
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    server = 'http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dump',
    data = 'universe=expanding&answer=42';

page.open(server, 'post', data, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to post!');
    } else {
        console.log(page.content);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Source: [Here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/post.js)

Comment: I have tried it before. First, I got `Error: Cannot find module 'webpage'`. Then after installing webpage using `npm install webpage`, I got `TypeError: require(...).create is not a function`

Comment: @NoName don't run this in node.js, run it with PhantomJS directly

Comment: @NoName, Vaviloff is right. You have to run phantomJS directly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to download PhantomJS from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Install it and then move the executable from the `bin` folder to the `PATH` of your file. Finally, open a new file, paste [this code](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/post.js), and run from your command prompt: `phantomjs [name of your file]`.